# Is "Multiple Include Guard" required for .cpp files?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have file1.h and file1.cpp in my project. I have multiple include Guard in file1.h to avoid multiple inclusions of same file. I have include file1.h file in file1.cpp file.  I run a third party tool (parasoft) to find any issues which with respect to the project, it has identified Multiple Include Guard is missing in file1.cpp file. My question is it required to have Multiple Include Guard in file1.cpp file? If not required why  am I getting error in file*.cpp file? Please help me....

Comment: **Multiple** include Guards for one file?

Comment: Well, it's name is Header guard, for a reason. I think parasoft is just stupid. :( (unfortunately, i know parasoft cause of my work...)

Comment: is there any compile error messages?

Comment: @Jarod42: "multiple-include guards". The guard guards against multiple inclusion. But yeah, the normal name is just include _include guard_

Answer (score 5):

The usual cause of this message is `#include "file1.cpp"`. That is to say, you accidentally included the .cpp file instead of the actual header.

The tool you're using correctly thinks that if `file1.cpp` is included, then it should be guarded against multiple inclusion. The tool doesn't wonder whether `file1.cpp` should have been included in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you are using is either broken, or you are not using it correctly.
You don't need any include guard in a cpp file because normally you wouldn't include cpp file anywhere.

Comment: maybe he is including the source file and thus gets the warning

Comment: That could be possible explanation. But he described exactly which files he has and how they are included. If the file1.cpp was included somewhere else, I hope he would write so.